# How to pass ViewData value to Partial View using @url in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my Project i need to pass value partial value while click button.
So i tried like this

```
<div id="searchgrid" class="col-lg-12">
  @Html.Partial("ResultGrid", new List<SCM_MVC.Models.User>(), 
  new ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData) { { "index" , xEdit } })
</div>

<script src="~/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    var url = '@Url.Action("ResultGrid", "User")', new { xEdit : ViewData["Form"] };
    $('#btnloadgrid').click(function () {
        $('#searchgrid').load(url);
    })
</script>
```

While open View its Working. But Click button its not working. What am doing wrong in jquery function?

Comment: `var url = '@Url.Action("ResultGrid", "User")', new { xEdit : ViewData["Form"] };` will create an invalid output in the JS. If you check the actual rendered code (and the console) you'll see the syntax issues.

Comment: What is `ViewData["Form"]`? That would only work if its a simple value (and the `new { .. }` would need to be withing the `Url.Action()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url` declaration is syntactically wrong as checked in .NET fiddle:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("ResultGrid", "User")', new { xEdit : ViewData["Form"] };
//                                             ^ Syntax error: Unexpected token 'new'
```

The correct way is either wrap route value parameters inside `UrlHelper.Action` helper:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("ResultGrid", "User", new { xEdit = ViewData["Form"] })';
```

Or by using old-fashioned query string if the value passed from client-side variable:

```
var viewData = '@ViewData["Form"]';

var url = '@Url.Action("ResultGrid", "User")?xEdit=' + viewData;
```

Both ways produce URL as in example below (`ViewData["Form"]` must be such like plain numeric or string value):

```
/User/ResultGrid?xEdit=someValue
```